# bash + how to match string that include characters and numbers

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

please advice - what's wrong with my syntax ? ( should not print the "bad interface " )

remark -  I work with bash shell

```
ETH_NAME=eth0         ( or any other as eth1 or eth2 .... )
echo $ETH_NAME

eth0 



[ $ETH_NAME  != eth[0-9] ] && echo bad interface
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`[[ ... ]]`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) compound command which can do pattern matching with `!=`

```
$ ETH_NAME=eth0
$ [[ $ETH_NAME != eth[0-9] ]] && echo bad interface
$ ETH_NAME=eth01
$ [[ $ETH_NAME != eth[0-9] ]] && echo bad interface
bad interface
```

Comment: Another option would be a regular expression: `[[ ! $ETH_NAME =~ ^eth[0-9]$ ]]`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Yes, but you still need to use `[[` rather than `[` which is what the OPs problem was.

Comment: I didn't claim anything different.

Answer (score 2):

Or use the standard (POSIX sh) `case` statement instead of ksh's `[[...]]` (also found in bash and zsh).

```
case $ETH_NAME in
  (eth[0-9]) ;;
  (*) echo >&2 bad interface
esac
```

Note that it will say that eth10 is a bad interface.

You could instead do

```
case $ETH_NAME in
  (eth|eth*[!0-9]*) echo >&2 bad interface;;
  (eth*) ;;
  (*) echo >&2 bad interface
esac
```

(note that network interfaces names including ethernet ones are not limited to `ethx`).

Comment: This one is my favorite, since it's fast and `/bin/sh`-compatible

Comment: Note that it's not `/bin/sh` compatible (as some `/bin/sh` like the Bourne shell still found on some systems are not POSIX and don't accept that syntax) but it is POSIX sh compatible so would work in any POSIX conformant shell.

Comment: Actually it is, but I have no idea why you use opening `(`. Every manual from BSD's till Solaris have mentions of `case…esac` but uses `pattern) list` syntax.

Comment: Yes, the leading "(" is POSIX but not Bourne. It is more legible, helps with bracket matching in vi, avoid parsing issues in some shells inside `$(...)`. It is supported by all POSIX shells and IIRC the Almquist shell (even the original one before it was made POSIX), so basically all Bourne-like shells but the Bourne shell. It breaks Bourne compatibility.

Comment: Ok, bracket matching is cool thing, but ability to not require `/bin/bash` and be more portable is of a higher importance (as to me). )

Comment: No. it's not what I said. POSIX now defines "sh". What it also says is that the POSIX "sh" might not be in "/bin" and that the behavior when a script starts with "#!" is _unspecified_. `case...in (..)` is perfectly fine in a `sh` script, simply not necessarily in a `/bin/sh` script. Just don't write `/bin/sh` scripts, just scripts without a `#!` line (and avoid Solaris).

Comment: Before being a POSIX shell, `/bin/sh` used to be a Bourne shell (and still is in Solaris which is the only notable exception), but before that it was even something completely different. There's not point trying to be portable as far back as the Thomson shell, and IMO there's no point being portable as far back as the Bourne shell either.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way of doing that matching is `case…esac`:

```
case "$ETH_NAME" in
    eth[0-9]) ;;
    *) echo 'bad interface' ;;
esac
```

since it's [fast](http://poige.livejournal.com/573575.html?thread=3794055#t3794055) and rather portable (doesn't require using `bash`). I can't say that subset of regexps available for `case` is a rich one, but often it's sufficient.